# Singly linked list simple database

Tags: c, linked-list

Im trying to figure out how can I create database using singly linked lists. I want to hold in 1 node for example 1 client and few items can't figure it out for like 3 days now how should I do it, here's one example of how i tried to do it. Tried aswell to nest item list inside client but failed aswell. So if anyone would be kind enough to provide example or say exactly what should i correct in this code or maybe provide better answer to my problem it would be great,thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct item
{
    char item_name[30];
    struct item *next;
};
struct client
{
    char name[30];
    char last_name[30];
    struct client *next;
};
struct node
{
    int NodeNr;
    struct item *HeadItem;
    struct item *TailItem;
    struct client *HeadClient;
    struct client *TailClient;
    struct node *next;
};
struct client *create_node()
{
        int x;
        char name[30];
        struct client *data = malloc(sizeof(struct client));
        printf("Name: ");
       scanf("%s",name);
       strcpy(data->name,name);
         printf("Last Name: ");
        scanf("%s",name);
       strcpy(data->last_name,name);
    printf("Person : %s %s is added.\n", data->name,data->last_name);
    return data;
}
struct node *AddClient(struct node *HeadNode,struct client *data)
{
    if(HeadNode->HeadClient = NULL)
    {
        HeadNode -> HeadClient = data;
        HeadNode -> TailClient = data;
        data ->next = NULL;
        HeadNode -> next = NULL;

    }
    else
    {
        data -> next = NULL;
      HeadNode-> next -> TailClient = data;
      HeadNode -> TailClient = data;
    }
    return HeadNode;
}
struct node *Display (struct node *HeadNode)
{
    while(HeadNode->HeadClient =! NULL)
    {
        printf("%s",HeadNode->HeadClient->name,HeadNode->HeadClient->last_name);
        HeadNode->HeadClient =HeadNode->HeadClient->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    struct node *temp;
    AddClient(temp,create_node());
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the code supposed to do, and what is the issue you're seeing? "Create database" is much too general a description.

Comment: Have you tried compiling this code with compiler warnings on? You should.

Comment: I tried compiling it and it compiles without any warnings in codeblocks, overall it crashes after adding client .
I want to be abble to add how many items I want to 1 client using singly linked lists

Comment: use a pice of paper and draw boxes (for malloc'ed things) and arrows for next-pointers and then put some elements in oyur list, and you will see that your else case is suspect, because you always will destroy what HeadNode->next points to

Comment: Also, simplify your data structures. At the moment you have many things that you don't need right now. I'm not sure what you mean with "head clients" and "tail clients", for example. Make that one node - one client.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, first step: compiler warnings on. This will turn up the following bugs:

```
if(HeadNode->HeadClient = NULL) ...
```

This should be a comparison with `==`. It is easy to mix up assignment `=` and comparison for equality `==` and the C language allows this.

```
while(HeadNode->HeadClient =! NULL) ...
```

This is just as easy to overlook: The comparison for inequality is `!=` with the exclamation first first. (Mnemonic: It means not `!` equal `=`). You've swapped the symbols and effectively created two operators: you assign (`=`) the value of `!NULL` to `HeadNode->HeadClient`. The value of "not null" is 1, which makes the condition always true. That would mean that the loop runs forever - if `0x1`was a valid pointer. Bit it isn't, so the program crashed when dereferencing `HeadNode->HeadClient`.

```
printf("%s\n",
        HeadNode->HeadClient->name, HeadNode->HeadClient->last_name);
```

You've got one format specifier in your format string and two arguments after the format. That's not as bad as the other way round, but not what you intended.

Your real problem is that the head node `temp`, that you pass from `main` isn't initialised. The way `AddClient` works, it needs to be referenced, so initialising it to `NULL` won't help. You have to initialise it to some data, which probably involves `malloc`.

It would be better to re-organise your program to start with an empty list represented by a `NULL` pointer. Also, you should allocate memory for every new node, which you don't. You function `AddClient` should append a new node (with its own newly allocated memory) to the end of the list. it should ensure that the `next` pointer of the last item is `NULL`.

When the first node is added, you will change the head pointer. Therefore, you must either pass a pointer to pointer to node to the function, or you must return the new value of the head pointer, so that the change will be reflected in subsequent calls

Also, the routine that creates a node is called `AddClient`, the routine that creates a client is called `create_node`. That's recipe for disaster!

Answer (score 0):

you want to use a single linked list, so i would skip the Tail part until you have that working (which means you always have to run to the previous to the last element to add things), and then you can improve the code by putting a Tail to the structures